# Php, Mysql distinctor grouped query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling, creating a mysql query for the following scenario:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [qid_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 1
            [question] => Favorite Place
            [answer] => New York
            [username] => john
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [qid_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 1
            [question] => Additional Info
            [answer] => N/A
            [username] => john
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [qid_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 1
            [question] => Favorite Place
            [answer] => London
            [username] => peter
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [qid_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 1
            [question] => Additional Info
            [answer] => N/A
            [username] => peter
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [qid_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 2
            [question] => Favorite Place
            [answer] => Sidney
            [username] => mike
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [qid_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 2
            [question] => Additional Info
            [answer] => N/A
            [username] => mike
        )
)
```

I'm trying to display data in html table, and so far I got the following:

```
      $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT question"
      . "\n FROM faq " 
      . "\n WHERE qid_id = 1";
      $data = $db->fetchAll($sql);  

      $sql2 = "SELECT f.*, u.username"
      . "\n FROM faq as f" 
      . "\n LEFT JOIN users as u on u.id = f.user_id "
      . "\n WHERE f.qid_id = 1";
      $data2 = $db->fetchAll($sql2);    

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <?php
      print "<th>USERNAME</th>";
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
          print "<th>" . $data[$i]->question . "</th>";
      }
     ?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
```

The above works fine, I'm having problem displaying the rest of the table, using second query ($data2). I'm not sure how to group fields in order to get unique results for each row.

The idea is to have something like:

```
USERNAME    Favorite Place      Additional Info
john        New York            N/A
peter       London              N/A 
mike        Sidney              N/A
```

Comment: Please, could you explain what you want to do? I don't understand why you are doing two select queries on the same table.

Comment: @Pedro Moreira If it could be done with one query, it's even better, the final result needs to be the html table at the bottom of the question